# Error en el servidor con NextJs y Framer Motion

Tags: css, reactjs, animación, next.js

Estoy tratando de animar las cards cuando se renderiza el componente pero tengo un error. Parece haber una discrepancia entre el HTML inicial generado en el servidor y el HTML que React intenta renderizar en el cliente. Esto puede ocurrir cuando el contenido generado en el servidor y el contenido generado en el cliente no coinciden. :
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
    import React from 'react';
import { motion } from 'framer-motion';
import StyleCard from './StyleCard';
import { stylesOptions } from '@/utils/styles';

const itemFramerMotion = {
  hidden: { y: 20, opacity: 0 },
  visible: {
    y: 0,
    opacity: 1
  }
};

function StyleCardContainer(): JSX.Element {
  return (
    <div className='w-[100%] max-w-[1090px] flex-col mx-auto'>
      <div className='my-6 mx-auto text-center'>
        <h1 className='text-4xl lowercase font-semibold'>Vision Inspiradora</h1>
        <h2 className='uppercase tracking-wider font-semibold'>
          Elegí tu estilo
        </h2>
      </div>
      <div className='w-[100%] grid tablet:grid-cols-3 gap-4'>
        {stylesOptions.map((item, index) => (
          <motion.div
            key={index}
            initial='hidden'
            animate='visible'
            variants={itemFramerMotion}
          >
            <StyleCard
              key={index}
              title={item.title}
              description={item.description}
              image={item.image}
            />
          </motion.div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default StyleCardContainer;
```